# Problema ao girar tela celular android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Olá, estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo para android usando o xamarin, tenho no aplicativo um webbrowser, bem simples, onde ele acessa uma página de login ( http://portaldopatchwork.klickmembersproject.com.br/login ) , aí depois que eu faço login nesta página normal, se eu rotacionar a tela a pagina volta para a tela de login, porque ? quando a tela é virada, o webbrowser recarrega a página ? o que posso fazer para que isso não ocorra e continue na página de logada sem deslogar? Obrigado

Comment: Você implementa alguma função que é disparada ao virar a tela?

Comment: não, eu não configurei nada, eu basicamente só criei um webbrowser , coloquei para ele abrir neste site e pronto, só isso

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Deve adicionar a flag `configChanges` com o valor `keyboardHidden`, `orientation` e `screenSize` no seu `Activity`

### No Xamarim

Pode-se adicionar as `flags` com [`Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges/) mais ou menos assim:

```c#
[Activity (Label = "@string/app_name", MainLauncher = true, Icon="@drawable/launcher",
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : ...
```

### No Manifest.xml

Eu não tenho certeza se o Xamarin disponibiliza o controle sobre o Manifest.xml gerado, mas se disponibilizar **na tag `<activity>`** adicione `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`, assim por exemplo:

```xml
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
```

### Salvando instancias

Não sei se para o Xamarin isto é necessário (ou se depende de uma versão mais recente do Android), mas se a configuração anterior não for o suficiente então salve as instancias:

### Se estiver em CSharp

Adicione aos métodos (ou crie eles) com *override*:

```c#
private WebView minhaWebView; //Se a sua webView nesta variável

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
}

protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
    base.OnSaveInstanceState(outState); //Salva Activity
    minhaWebView.SaveState(outState);   //Salva WebView
}

protected override void OnRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnRestoreSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState); //Restaura o Activity
    minhaWebView.RestoreState(savedInstanceState);       //Restaura o WebView
}
```

### Se estiver em Java

```java
private WebView minhaWebView; //Defina a webView nesta variável

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState); //Salva Activity
    minhaWebView.saveState(outState);    //Salva WebView
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState); //Restaura o Activity
    minhaWebView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);    //Restaura o WebView
}
```

### Documentação Xamarin

- [Android.App.Activity.OnCreate](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.OnCreate/p/Android.OS.Bundle/)
- [Android.App.Activity.OnSaveInstanceState](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.OnSaveInstanceState/p/Android.OS.Bundle/)
- [Android.App.Activity.OnRestoreInstanceState](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.App.Activity.OnRestoreInstanceState/p/Android.OS.Bundle/)

Answer (score 1):

As Activities no Android são destruídas e recriadas quando a tela gira. Você precisa salvar os dados necessários num Bundle antes dela ser destruída no método onSaveInstanceState() e depois restaurar os dados do Bundle  no OnCreate caso ele não seja nulo.

Maiores detalhes aqui: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

Para complementar, um atalho a qual você pode recorrer é o uso do setRetainInstance(true);, assim seus problemas com persistência quando sua activity ou fragment for destruída, estarão resolvidos, em parte. xD

Comment: Eu não chamaria isso de atalho (senão seria o método oficial, rs). É importante entender o ciclo de vida das Activities. A recomendação é que o desenvolvedor sempre faça a gestão das mudanças de estado da Activity para garantir que a aplicação não vai dar pau. Esse método que você citou só funciona para Fragment e só deveria ser usado quando você quer lidar com a algum processamento grande que não deveria ser perdido na recriação da Activity (Ex: AsyncTask, Threads, etc). Mas mesmo assim, não há garantia que o Android irá manter o estado caso os recursos estejam baixos e aí o app pode dar pau.

Comment: Opa, obrigado pelo aviso.